# Poor performance from `gstat::krige` with a noise predictor

Tags: r, predictive-models, kriging

I'm new to kriging, and I'm considering replacing a use of inverse-distance weighting (IDW) in a spatial modeling project (implemented with `gstat::idw` in R) with a kriging-based approach (implemented with `gstat::krige`). On my first attempt, I got poor predictive accuracy. I've been playing around with simulations to figure out what's going on, and it looks like when `krige` gets one noise predictor, compared to no predictors, it tanks. Is this a bug in `gstat` or some way in which universal kriging is vastly more prone to overfitting than, say, linear regression? What's going on?

Here's an example:

```
library(gstat)

set.seed(1000)
n = 1000
d = data.frame(
    train = c(rep(T, .7*n), rep(F, .3*n)),
    x = runif(n, 0, 10),
    y = runif(n, 0, 10),
    noise = rnorm(n))
d = transform(d, outcome = (x - 5)^2 + (y - 5)^2 + rnorm(n, sd = 2))

obs = d[!d$train, "outcome"]

tryit = function(my.formula)
   {preds = gstat::krige(
        formula = my.formula,
        locations = ~ x + y,
        data = d[d$train,],
        newdata = d[!d$train,],
        debug.level = 0)[, "var1.pred"]
    message("RMSE: ", sqrt(mean((obs - preds)^2)))}

message("SD: ", sd(obs))
tryit(outcome ~ 1)
tryit(outcome ~ 1 + noise)
```

The output is:

```
SD: 10.8120249379363
RMSE: 3.68179409633032
RMSE: 10.7943966111937
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem was lack of a variogram model. I'm not actually sure how `krige` handles this situation, but perhaps it has a default variogram model fitting procedure which is inadequate.

In any case, a variogram model can be automatically fitted using package `automap`, which is the easiest option.

Please see below two calculation of RMSE - 
1. Ordinary Kriging (`outcome ~ 1`)
2. Universal Kriging (`outcome ~ noise`)

As could be expected, the RMSE is almost identical in both cases (RMSE=`2.17`) since the noise has no contribution in explaining the trend.

```
library(sp)
library(gstat)
library(automap)

set.seed(1000)
n = 1000
d = data.frame(
    train = c(rep(T, .7*n), rep(F, .3*n)),
    x = runif(n, 0, 10),
    y = runif(n, 0, 10),
    noise = rnorm(n))
d = transform(d, outcome = (x - 5)^2 + (y - 5)^2 + rnorm(n, sd = 2))

# To points
pnt = d
coordinates(pnt) = ~ x + y

# Observed
bubble(pnt, "outcome")
```

[image]

```r
# Ordinary Kriging
f = outcome ~ 1
v = autofitVariogram(formula = f, input_data = pnt)
g = gstat(formula = f, data = pnt[pnt$train, ], model = v$var_model)
pred = predict(object = g, newdata = pnt[!pnt$train, ])
```

```
## [using ordinary kriging]
```

```r
pred$resid = pnt$outcome[!pnt$train] - pred$var1.pred
bubble(pred, "var1.pred")
```

[image]

```r
bubble(pred, "resid")
```

[image]

```r
sqrt(mean((pred$resid)^2))
```

```
## [4] 2.173127
```

```r
# Universal Kriging
f = outcome ~ noise
v = autofitVariogram(formula = f, input_data = pnt)
g = gstat(formula = f, data = pnt[pnt$train, ], model = v$var_model)
pred = predict(object = g, newdata = pnt[!pnt$train, ])
```

```
## [using universal kriging]
```

```r
pred$resid = pnt$outcome[!pnt$train] - pred$var1.pred
bubble(pred, "var1.pred")
```

[image]

```r
bubble(pred, "resid")
```

[image]

```r
sqrt(mean((pred$resid)^2))
```

```
## [4] 2.171701
```